# How do I animate ListView item hights?

Tags: android, listview, animation

I have a simple ListView in my application. What I want to do on a row select is to expand it and show additional details in there and then if some other is selected then collapse the previous one and expand the new one.

I can modify the contents list item row in `onListItemClick()` method. However how do I animate the change in height of the list item row.

Is there a better way to do it? Or is there a better component still? I don't want to use the expandable list as it's not a group of child lists, instead just expanding the contents with more details.

Any help is much appreciated.
Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at Lazylist below this.

http://open-pim.com/tmp/LazyList.zip

i think this example is great for build your custom ListView

Comment: You expect us to download some random zip file off the internet, without even an explanation of what it contains or how it relates to the question?